# DraggableScrollableSheet sets initialChildSize without animation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following widget structure. And my question: Is it possible to my DraggableScrollableSheet sets his initial size with scroll animation?

```
...
child: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: onWillPop,
            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              initialChildSize: widget.convertSnapValue(widget.initialExpansion),
              snap: true,
              snapSizes: _snapSizes,
              minChildSize: 0,
              controller: _sheetController,
              builder: (context, scrollController) => _content(scrollController),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Comment: how much it will scroll after opening the `DraggableScrollableSheet` ? And about the title, I am not getting well, can you describe more or including a gif of your desire output will make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

u can set initialsize:0 and after rebuild finish, animateTo size that u want with controller?

Comment: yes, i know this solution... but seems to be not so good...